# Using Google Cloud DLP Stored infotype and getting 400 Invalid built-in info type name

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I have a stored infotype in the ready state on my DLP dashboard.  Its name is `Federal_Income_Tax`.

Using the python example at https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/concepts-infotypes I see the following:

```
info_types = [{"name": info_type} for info_type in info_types]
```

I have changed it to look for my stored infotype

```
info_types_to_locate = [{"name": "Federal_Income_Tax"}]
```

I have also provided my google_application_credentials and an active project ID.

When called it returns `400 Invalid built-in info type` name `Federal_Income_Tax`.

What is the syntax to indicate I wish to use a stored infotype rather than a built-in infotype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add the stored infoTypes you want to use to the `customInfoTypes` array. See documentation: https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/creating-stored-infotypes#scan_content_using_stored_custom_dictionary_detectors

[`inspectConfig.infoTypes`](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/inspecting-text#inspecting_a_text_string) is for built-in infoTypes only.